# Как устроены алгоритмы вычисление матриц "matlab"?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, matlab, распараллеливание

Как устроены вычисления в matlab? В частности, как он работает с матрицами? Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить, или дать ссылки на соответствующую литературу?

Предыстория такова, что я на с++ создал класс для работы с матрицами. Но когда я устроил тест на скорость умножения матриц в матлабе и матриц своего класса, то оказалось, что матлаб с вычислениями справляется почти в 200 раз быстрее.

О своём классе.
Шаблонный класс содержит в себе данные о размере матрицы и указатель на одномерный массив, который хранит в себе подряд строки матрицы, так как я предполагал, что с одномерным массивом вычисления будут идти быстрее. Так же, обращался к элементам массива, вычисляя их адрес вручную, так как оказалось, что иногда это работало на много быстрее, чем обращение к элементу массива через индекс. Но этого оказалось мало. Время на умножение матриц в матлабе так же имеет кубическую зависимость от размера матриц. Возникли предположения о том, что вычисления проводятся через видеокарту, или существует какой-то очень быстрый алгоритм умножения матриц, или, возможно, мой класс на столько не оптимизирован. Все остальные операции с матрицами матлаб тоже проводит на много быстрее.

Comment: *"так как я предполагал, что с одномерным массивом вычисления будут идти быстрее"* - программирование - наука экспериментальная. Написал, промерил, сделал выводы...

Comment: MATLAB для работы с матрицами использует одну из реализаций библиотек BLAS+LAPACK (может использовать даже оптимизированные MKL или OpenBLAS, но это за отдельные деньги, скорее всего). Почитать о том, как проводятся вычисления в BLAS/LAPACK можно на netlib.org (родина этих библиотек) или частично в книге *Дж. Деммель "Вычислительная линейная алгебра"* (есть в переводе).

Comment: @Vladimir Интересная книга, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорость матричных вычислений сильно зависит от того, как расположены данные в памяти, используются ли SIMD инструкции и раскрутка циклов. Это зависит от применяемого компилятора и его настроек. Выкладывайте ваш код, погладим.

В настоящее время, написание собственной линейной алгебры актуально только в учебных целях, и далеко не факт, что вы обгоните ATLAS, MKL или другие библиотеки - методы подгонки кода под процессор там очень жестокие, и если не знать особенностей конкретного чипа - фиг вы догоните корифеев.

Выгрузка же вычислений на видеокарту увеличивает скорость расчетов на порядки, и усложняет разработку на те же порядки.

Ну и про алгоритмы - наверняка большие матрицы матлаб щелкает по алгоритму Штрассена, потому что делать это в лоб смысла никакого нет.

Comment: обязательно ознакомлюсь с SIMD инструкциями и алгоритмом Штрассена.
Не знаю как код залить.

Comment: Правильно выкладывать код на гитхаб, в крайнем случае - накопипаcтить его в ideone.com

Comment: Ну вот, как-то попытался загрузить код. github.com/Cold-creeper/matrix/blob/master/mat